# Make object look at a point using Three js

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

I have a cube placed on a three js scene.
I want it to look at, rotate to, a point in space.

The code I use for this is this:

```
cube.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
```

With this line I want it to look up.

But it doesn't work. Any clues? Here's a codepen for is.

https://codepen.io/arpo/pen/NaPyaN?editors=0010

Edit: Pen updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the cube's default look direction is down the z-axis. So your arrow must start in that direction before the cube is rotated:

```
var arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), origin, length, hex);
```